# Dublin transit visa requirements for Indian citizens

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, ireland

My wife was not allowed to board her flight from Bangalore to the UK via Frankfurt and Dusseldorf as the Lufthansa staff claimed she needed a Shengen visa to take the flight from Frankfurt to Dusseldorf. She has an Indian passport with a valid UK spouse visa for 2 years.

I'm currently trying to book her on another flight and I've seen one going from Bangalore to Manchester,UK via Abu Dhabi and Dublin. I'm worried that the same issue may come up again in Dublin. Would she require a transit visa in this scenario to enter Dublin?

Also were the Lufthansa staff correct in not letting her board the original flight. I'm sure I've read that spouses of British Citizens are amongst those exempt from airport transit visa requirements in Germany?

Comment: Does that mean that you are a British National? The Lufthansa staff were correct, she won't need an Airport Transit Visa, she would need a Uniform 'C' Schengen visa because a flight from Frankfurt to Dusseldorf would be Intra-Schengen.

Comment: Yes I'm a British National. Any idea if she needs a transit or vistor visa to go from India via Dublin ?

Comment: The UK and RoI share some common immigration rules (the [Common Travel Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area)), but not all. You'll need to look up if a UK Spouse Visa is valid in Ireland under the CTA or not

Comment: As for her intra-schengen flight, was she travelling on her own, or with you? (The rules for spouses of EU citizens vary on if they're travelling along or with their spouse)

Answer (score 1):

### Traveling by herself through Ireland

She would need a visa for Ireland, however would not be required to pay the fee under the ["Short Stay Visa Programme" with countries including India](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Irish%20Short-stay%20Visa%20Waiver%20Programme%20Extension). She can only using enter using the [Common Travel Area rules if she is a visitor to the UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/common-travel-area-cta/common-travel-area-cta#cta5-the-republic-of-ireland). The [visitors to the UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/immigration-rules-part-2) section outlines the following:

> This covers people visiting the UK (not settling) and includes:
>
> - people coming for tourism, to visit friends and family or to do short    courses of study
> - unpaid academic, business, sports and entertainment activities
> - permitted paid engagements
> - people travelling to another country (‘in transit’)
> - private medical treatment
> - parents of children at schools in the UK
> - visiting just for marriage or civil partnership
> - the ‘Approved Destination Scheme’ agreement with China
> - Commonwealth Games family members

She does not need a visa if she holds an EU Residence card.

> You are a family member of an EU citizen and you hold a document
>   called "Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen" as
>   referred to in article 10 of Directive 2004/38/EC (pdf).
>
> [Source](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/coming_to_live_in_ireland/visa_requirements_for_entering_ireland.html)

### Traveling with you

She can [travel within the Schengen zone without a visa](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm) as long as she is accompanying you.

Comment: The original question asked about transit visas at Dublin Airport but the answer above seems to deal with visa requirements to enter Ireland. Nationals of some countries require transit visas (https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36840/dublin-transit-visa-for-sri-lankan-citizens) but India is not one of those countries: http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Transit%20visas